# will the size of the memory RAM using virtualBox be allocate on my host memory forever?

Tags: virtualbox, memory, virtual-machine

I'm trying to create a virtual machine with a 4GB RAM but I'm not sure if the space requested will be temporality borrowed by the virtual machine or it will be allocated forever.

I would really appreciate if anyone can explain me how really allocation of memory works in virtualBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you allocate RAM to a virtual machine, that RAM is only available to the machine while the virtual machine is running.  When the virtual machine is offline, the RAM is free for the host OS.  The only thing that is permanent, is the virtual hard disk (if you use one).

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I was trying to get the windows 8 on my mac and i wasn't sure about how the memory allocation works. thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

When I used virtual machines, my ram was only borrowed from when the VM was OPEN. When it was closed and turned off, it wasn't, and when I deleted it, nothing changed with my ram.